# "Language neutral" is not showing up in views?

Tags: view, drupal-7

I am creating a view for displaying content having fields like title, type, language, author, etc., but language field having value as Language neutral are not showing up in views of Drupal 7.

Can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
By using rewrite result option of views, that issue can be handled.
Steps are as follows :

1. Enable Views PHP module.
2. Go to desired view and check 'exclude from display' in language field. 
3. Add a field of type Global: PHP.
4. In Output field write this code :


<?php 
if($row->language == 'und') {
 echo 'Language Neutral';
}
if($row->language == 'en') {
 echo 'English';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just set the Language field "No Results Behavior" text to "Language Neutral", that way it will print the Language if it is set, and Language Neutral if a Language has not been set.

Language Neutral in Drupal is really just the Language field not having a value.